# select last set of rows in time range with DateFrameGroupBy object

Tags: python, pandas

I got the following code to work with a DateFrame object.

    `lastwk = g.apply(lambda x: x[ x['realtime'] > (x['realtime'].iloc[-1] - dtt.timedelta(7)) ])`

When I use this DateFrameGroupBy object: the above code doesnt work.
>

```
<class 'pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy'>
('g', variable  subject_id             realtime  hr1
0                 1  2012-09-27 04:15:00   22
1                 1  2012-09-27 04:31:00   10
2                 1  2012-09-27 04:47:00   2
3                 1  2012-09-27 05:10:00   2
4                 1  2012-09-27 05:37:00   6
203                9  2012-12-12 13:33:00   6
205                9  2012-12-12 14:08:00   14
```

I am mostly getting this error:
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'unicode' and 'datetime.timedelta'`

This works for a different datset that is wide.  Weird that the long and tidy has caused so much grief.

anyhow any help is appreciated.

--edit--

here is some code to check the type of the `realtime` col in the groupby g, and to also manually go through and type in a lambda:

```
print 'time type', type(g['realtime'] )
tme = g['realtime'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x) )
print 'yo yo' #bugs are fun
print 'time type&&&', type(tme )
```

here is the output:
no luck!
>

```
time type <class 'pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy'>
yo yo
time type&&& <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

(( -- i upgraded from 0.10 to 0.14, to get .iloc() indexing, and this seems to be one of the problems that has cropped in...
have had trouble with other datasets as well --ugh ))

--edit or (welcome to unicode city_ where the girls are pretty) :

```
dt = dt.reset_index() 
print '### 1', dt['realtime'].dtype, dt['realtime'].apply(type) 
dt['realtime'] = pd.to_datetime( dt['realtime'] ) 
print '### 2', dt['realtime'].dtype, dt['realtime'].apply(type) 
dt['time'] = pd.to_datetime( dt['realtime'] ) 
print '### 3', dt['time'].dtype, dt['time'].apply(type) 
exit(0)
```

outputs: 
`Name: realtime, Length: 1982, dtype: object`
`Name: time, Length: 1982, dtype: object`

checked the type of dt:
`type dt <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`

Comment: what's `dtype` of `realtime`? looks like it's `unicode` rather than `datetime.datetime`

Comment: @syntax: Happy001 asked to see the dtype of `realtime`.  You showed the *type* of what you get when you select a column from a groupby object (`SeriesGroupBy`), and the *type* of an unrelated Series after you apply `pd.to_datetime` to its elements, which by construction is `Series`.  So far, nothing you've shown is incompatible with the error message `pandas` gave, which says that you're trying to subtract a `timedelta` from a `unicode` string.  Instead, look at `df['realtime'].dtype`, and `df["realtime"].apply(type)`.